# how to shorten if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am trying to shorten a series of if/else statements that I have created. The code works just fine, but it seems redundant at the moment. I was trying to implement a loop to do this, I couldn't figure out how to handle the "indexOf("")" for each statement in the loop.

Here is my code:

```
    window.addEventListener("load", (event)=>{

      $("div.faq-container").hide();
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("shipping") > -1) {
      $("div.faq-container").eq( "0" ).show();
    }
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("returns") > -1) {
      $("div.faq-container").eq( "1" ).show();
    }
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("custom") > -1) {
      $("div.faq-container").eq( "2" ).show();
    }
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("replacements") > -1) {
      $("div.faq-container").eq( "3" ).show();
    }
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("mostFAQs") > -1) {
      $("div.faq-container").eq( "4" ).show();
    }
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("RAD") > -1) {
      $("div.faq-container").eq( "5" ).show();
    }
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("environmental") > -1) {
      $("div.faq-container").eq( "6" ).show();
    }
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("USA") > -1) {
      $("div.faq-container").eq( "7" ).show();
    }
    else{
      $("div.faq-container").eq( "0" ).show();
    }

    })
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at `switch-case` in Javascript here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch .

Comment: This question might be better suited at [codereview.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use an array for each value, arrays also use a zero index, so you could then use indexOf into the array to grab the index.

eg.

```
const lu = ['shipping', 'returns', 'custom', 'replacements',
  'mostFAQs', 'RAD', 'environmental', 'USA'
];

window.addEventListener("load", (event)=>{
  $("div.faq-container").hide();
  for (let ix = 0; ix < lu.length; ix += 1) {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(lu[ix]) > -1) {
      $("div.faq-container").eq(ix.toString()).show();
      return;
    }  
  }
  $("div.faq-container").eq( "0" ).show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With a loop you could do something like this:

```js
const url = window.location.href
const routes = ["shipping", "returns", "custom", "replacements", "mostFAQs", "RAD", "environmental", "USA"]
let solution = false

for (const {index, route} of routes.entries()) {
  if (url.indexOf(route) > -1) {
    $("div.faq-container").eq(`${index}`).show()
    solution = true
  }
}

if (!solution) $("div.faq-container").eq("0").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put the keys in an ordered array, and loop through them to see if they are included in the url. The some loop exits when it finds a true value.

Set the initial key value to 0 since that is your else case.

```js
const keys = ['shipping', 'returns', 'custom', 'replacements', 'mostFAQs', 'RAD', 'environmental', 'USA'];

let foundKey = 0;
keys.some((key, index) => {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf(key) > -1) {
    foundKey = index;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});

$("div.faq-container").eq(foundKey).show();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```